# How to use vba userform to make a toggle feature work for column?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, togglebutton

How would you then go about hiding/unhiding columns separately? From Columns C to M. This what I used for Hiding/ Unhiding set rows using toggle buttons.

```
Private Sub togbHAZOP_Click()
If togbHAZOP.Value = True Then
    Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Rows("5:26").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Rows("5:26").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: if you are tying to hide/unhide columns, you would want `Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Columns("C:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`

Comment: or Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Columns("C:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Comment: The `EntireRow` or `EntireColumn` is extraneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `Boolean` property being assigned to opposite Boolean values in opposing branches of a conditional expression involving a `Boolean` property. In other words:

```
If {bool} Then
    foo = True
Else
    foo = False
End If
```

There's no need for a conditional.

```
Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Rows("5:26").Hidden = togbHAZOP.Value
```

To toggle column visibility, use `.Columns` instead of `.Rows`, and a range address that represents columns instead of rows.

```
Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Columns("C:M").Hidden = togbHAZOP.Value
```

If you want them "separate", then *make them* separate..

```
Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Columns("C:C").Hidden = toggleForColumnC.Value
Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Columns("D:D").Hidden = toggleForColumnD.Value
Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Columns("E:E").Hidden = toggleForColumnE.Value
...
```

Answer (score 1):

For each toggle (togC, togB, ... togM) it would look like this

```
Private Sub togC_Click()
    Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Columns("C").Hidden = togC.Value
End If
```

...

```
Private Sub togD_Click()
    Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Columns("D").Hidden = togD.Value
End If
```

...

etc

Comment: I said separately not as set. For example having togbC, togbD....togbM so a toggle button for each column.

Comment: @SharathChander - Will you have all 10 toggles in a single frame (so that only one can be selected at a time)? Or just 10 separate toggle controls?

Comment: 10 separate toggle controls, so that the user can play with which columns to be hidden.

Comment: @SharathChander - I updated my answer. Hope it helps